# SAS Proc Optmodel Syntax and Strategy

Tags: optimization, sas

I have a data set that looks like this (SAS 9.4):

```
data opt_test;
        input ID GRP $ x1 MIN MAX y z;
cards;
2 F 10 9 11 1.5 100
3 F 10 9 11 1.2 50
4 F 11 9 11 .9 20
8 G 5 4 6 1.2 300
9 G 6 4 6 .9 200
;
run;
```

I want to create a new variable x2 that maximizes a function based on x1, x2, y, and z.

I am having two main problems:

1. The syntax on my proc optmodel has some errors that I have not been able to fix "Subscript 1 may not be a set" and constraint has incomplete declaration".  UPDATE: I figured this part out.
2. I need for the value of x2 to be the same for all members of the same GRP.  So, id 2,3,4 would have same x2.  ID 8 and 9 would have same x2.

Below is my attempt.  This will ultimately be able to run with sevarl different GRP of varying numbers of ID.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
proc optmodel;

set<num> ID;

var x2{ID} >= 0;
string GRP{ID};
number x1{ID}; 
number MIN{ID};
number MAX{ID}; 
number y{ID}; 
number z{ID}; 




max sales=sum{i in ID}(x2[i])*(1-(x2[i]-x1[i])*y[i]/x1[i])*z[i];

con floor_METRIC1{i in ID}: x2[i]>=MIN[i];
con ceiling_METRIC1{i in ID}: x2[i]<=MAX[i];

read data opt_test into
        ID=[ID]
        GRP
        x1 
        MIN 
        MAX 
        y 
        z 
        ;

solve;

print x2;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value of `x2` to be the same for all ids in the same group, then you only need one variable `x2` per group. To keep track of which ids are in which group you could use an array of sets indexed by group:

```
set<num> ID;

string GRP{ID};
set GRPS                 = setof{i in ID} GRP[i];
set IDperGRP{gi in GRPS} = {i in ID: GRP[i] = gi};
```

When you use `=` (as opposed to `init`), you provide OPTMODEL with a function you don't need to update later. If you change any of the GRP or ID data, optmodel will recompute GRPS and IDperGRP as needed.

Now you can use the `GRPS` set and the `IDperGRP` array of sets to rewrite your objective to more closely match your business rule:

```
max sales = sum{gi in GRPS} sum{i in IDperGRP[gi]} 
            (x2[gi]) * (1-(x2[gi]-x1[i])*y[i]/x1[i]) * z[i];
```

Writing the expression this way makes it clearer (to me at least) that it can be simplified further as long as `x1`, `y`, and `z` are constants.

Adding the new sets also makes it clearer (to me at least) that the bounds from `floor_METRIC1` and `ceiling_METRIC1` can be combined to tighten the domain of `x2`. Since `MIN` and `MAX` are constants, you can move the constraints into direct variable bounds by adding `>=` and `<=` clauses to the declaration of `x2`. Since `x2` will now depend on `MIN` and `MAX`, you will have to declare those before `x2`. IMHO that makes your intent clearer:

```
number MIN{ID};
number MAX{ID}; 
var x2{gi in GRPS} >= max{i in IDperGRP[gi]} MIN[i] 
                   <= min{i in IDperGRP[gi]} MAX[i] 
;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Leo.  This is great.  One further question if I may....How does this change the syntax of my create data statement?  I have:  create data results from [ID]={ID} x2 GRP x1 MIN MAX y z;

Comment: The simplest solution is to declare an implicit variable: `impvar x2byID{i in ID} = x2[GRP[i]];`, then refer to the implicit variable in your create data statement: `create data results from [ID]={ID} x2=x2byID GRP x1 MIN MAX y z;`